# Cannot resolve symbol 'String'

Tags: java, android, string

Why can't I use 'String' object in a Java class? It does not appear in the code suggestions.

[image]

I am getting this error: Cannot resolve symbol 'String'

[image]

Comment: Did you setup or select a JDK?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio "cannot resolve symbol String"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23445233/android-studio-cannot-resolve-symbol-string)

Comment: @Glains yes i did

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman i already to try invalidate and restart, but can't resolve teh problem

Comment: what about building? can you build the project with this error? if you can, the problem is with your IDE and you need to remove the IDE and all its configurations and install it again

Comment: @mohsen when i try build this project the result is complete successfully. it's mean your prediction maybe all right. and thanks for your advice

Comment: you're welcome, check this out [how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio-from-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39953495/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio-from-windowsv10)

Comment: You can try by selecting the menu item File and click on Invalidate Caches/Restart

This solution will work for some of the users not all

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me when I selected the correct JDK in Project Structure  and Reloaded the project from disk (right click & the reload option is present)

1. File > Project Structure
2. Select JDK , Apply and OK
3. Right click on project & the reload from disk
   [image]

Answer (score -2):

Project Structure > Set proper JDK available version. The issue will be indexed.